# Error when trying to create a one -to-many relationship between two flask_sqlalchemy tables: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I trying to create a relationship between a BlogPost table and a users table. Every time I try to run the program I receive this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: back_populates on relationship 'Users.posts' refers to attribute 'BlogPost.author' that is not a relationship.  The back_populates parameter should refer to the name of a relationship on the target class.
```

Here is my code:

```
##CONFIGURE TABLE
class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author")

##CONFIGURE TABLE
class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'blog_post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    author = db.relationship("Users", back_populates="posts") # lazy='dynamic'
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

I've been coming back to this and still can't figure out what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected code:

```
class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author")

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'blog_post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    author = db.relationship(Users, back_populates="posts")
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
```

Comment: You referenced the Users class in the BlogPost table relationship method, while I referenced it as a string. Thank you.